# How To Exclude Certain Relationship for Real-Time Prediction in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, prediction

So I'm working on a real-time prediction matter, for example, I have a node (A) (:Person) and he has friends and node (B) as (:Games)
so node (A) has liked a certain Game and his friends liked other games so I recommend those other games for him **But the matter is that I need to exclude the games which he is already liked or played**.
it seems to be easy around the 'NOT' command but I couldn't find the right code for it yet although I've tried a lot of ways
the one seems closest for me is like:

```
match (A:Person)-[:Friend]-(n:Person)
where A <> n
with distinct n
match (n)-[:LIKED]-(B:Game)-[:ON]-(:steam), (k:Person{name:'John'})
where not ((k)-[:LIKED]-(:Game)-[:ON]-(:steam))
return B
```

which has to recommend the games John's friends liked without the games which John already liked.

anyway, when I Run this, the Graph just freezes for a while and then shutdown which is another problem I want to ask for.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The last WHERE clause has very few constraints on it, and probably explains the hang/timeout.  It may help to have a variable name for each label, either to constrain the query or to receive the nodes.  more like this

where not ((k:Person{name:'John'})-[:LIKED]->(B:Game)-[:ON]->(C:steam))
return B

specify directional -> relationships (as above) in cypher queries if possible, usually it provides the answer you want, and is faster.

adding the variable name, and relationship direction also makes the query easier to read, to understand what it is doing, and if you need to look at the nodes/relationships values when debugging.

I may be wrong, but the :steam label doesn't look right to me.  What are example values?  I'm wondering if you meant to have a :service node, and steam would be a node instance?

Note: if you provide create nodes/rels script to create a small example of this database (e.g. a dozen nodes with these relationships) it would be easier to provide a working cypher example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the distinct games on Steam that John's friends liked but John has not yet liked or played, something this should work:

```
MATCH (j:Person{name:'John'})-[:FRIEND]-(:Person)-[:LIKED]->(g:Game)-[:ON]-(:steam)
WHERE NOT (j)-[:LIKED|PLAYED]->(g)
RETURN DISTINCT g
```